# how to use jquery time picker?

Tags: jquery, timepicker

dear all..i'm newbie at time picker.
can you tell me how to use jquery time picker after download?
how to make it show inside form?

Comment: which time picker?... don't make us wonder please...

Comment: i download from jquery.timepickr

Comment: @Reigel - I guess he must have tried the timepicker that topped the google results on searching for "jquery timepicker". :)

Comment: @ShiVik: yupz..i search using google.haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
$(function(){
    $('#test-1').timepickr({
        handle: '#trigger-test'
        convention: 12 });
});
```

You can put this script inside a  tag.

Then inside your form create a input field with id "test-1" in this case.

Check the full reference [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/UiTimepickr)